# Сделать фоновое изображение полупрозрачным

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, нужно сделать фоновое изображение полупрозрачным. Не весь блок, а только изображение.. играюсь с opacity, но никак не выходит выловить только изображение.. постоянно opacity действует и на весь блок тоже
[image]

В общем вопрос еще раз, как задать полупрозрачность только "галочке?"

Вот тут можете посмотреть [**исходники**](http://jsfiddle.net/RkmBD/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном виде на CSS2 точно никак.

Без потери верстки - добавьте после вопроса абсолютный див с фиксированными размерами и галочкой фоном, ему и ставьте opacity.

Comment: спасибо, получилось :)

Comment: а в IE6 получилось?)

Comment: Вообще я бы за кроссбраузер на 1-2 мажорные версии, а то уже "сколько ж можно". В любом случае, "crossbrowser opacity" оч хорошо гуглится.